# Randomly assigning two numbers to dataframe

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataframe in R which has one column  $Z$. I'm looking to add an extra column $X$ which consists of $0.5$ and $-0.5$, which indicate two 
different groups. My goal is to have as many people in group $0.5$ as in group $-0.5$. I've tried looking for solutions, but the only thing I've come across is the sample() function, which doesn't give equal groups, but just uses equal probability.

The code I've used so far is:

```
Z = rnorm(1000, 50, sd = 5)
df = data.frame(Z)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply replicate `-0.5` and `0.5` the value of `nrow(df) / 2` times each, then sample the population. This will create a random vector with an equal number of each value.

```
df$X <- sample(rep(c(-0.5, 0.5), nrow(df) / 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `sample` function I am creating a random order of rows. So I give your df rownames and the second df rownames. Than I am assinging 500 values with -0.5 and the rest with the value 0.5.

Run `random` more than once, to see that its completely random, but 0.5 and -0.5 exists 500 times in the final df.

```
library(tidyverse)
random <- function() {
  Z = rnorm(1000, 50, sd = 5)
  df = as_tibble(Z) %>% rename(Z=value) %>% rownames_to_column() # create column for merging

  result <- sample(1:1000) %>%
    as_tibble() %>% 
    mutate(X=ifelse(value>=500, 0.5, -0.5)) %>% # assigning 500 values with -0.5 and the rest with 0.5 
    rownames_to_column() %>% # rownumer as column
    right_join(df, by="rowname") %>% # merge both df's
    select(Z, X, -rowname, -value) # clean up columns
  print(result)
}

random()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution idea

Randomly select, without replacement, half the integers from 1 through the number of rows for one group; the complement is the other group.

Let's create a data frame for testing:

```
X <- data.frame(Z=rnorm(10))
```

Here's an `R` implementation of one solution:

```
n <- nrow(X)
X$Group <- ifelse(sample.int(n, n) * 2 <= n, 1/2, -1/2)
```

#### Generalization

To partition the data frame randomly into `g` groups, sample 1..n (which randomly permutes the row indexes) and reduce them modulo `g`:

```
g <- 2
X$Group <- factor(sample.int(n, n) %% g)
```

The counts of each group will all be within 1 of each other.